# Why was the following type incomplete?

Tags: c++, class

Consider the following simple program:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A; //1

namespace B
{
    struct A //2
    {
        int a;
        A() : a(10){ }
        friend void foo(A* a);
    };
}

void foo(A* a)
{
    std::cout << a -> a << std::endl;
}

A* a = new A; //error: allocation of incomplete type

int main()
{
    foo(a);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6fbd267a6a0ec85)**

In the code above we tried to allocate memory to incomplete type. But why is it incomplete? The Standard said `N3797::3.9/6 [basic.types]`:

> A class type (such as “class X”) might be incomplete at one point in a
>   translation unit and complete later on; the type “class X” is the same
>   type at both points.

So, the type `A` is incomplete at `//1` and has completed at `//2`, therefore as the Standard said it was the same at both points, which means class type is completed at `//1`. That is why the compile-error isn't clear to me. Couldn't you clarify?

Comment: Why do you think `B::A` counts as the type `A`?

Comment: "the type A is incomplete at //1 and has completed at //2" - How do you figure? I see an unrelated `B::A` defined at `//2`, followed by a friended `B::foo(B::A*)` that is never formally defined either. I blame exhaustion on my part if something different is actually there.

Comment: Moreover, `B::A` isn't complete at `//2` either. It's complete at the closing `}` of its definition. `::A` is never defined.

Comment: @T.C. But the name of _class A_ defined in _namespace B_ has external linkage (the innermost namespace linkage).

Comment: @DmitryFucintv Sure, but that has nothing to do with whether it and `::A` are the same thing.

Comment: @T.C. So, as far as I understand the definition of external linkage, an entity, denoted by a name with external linkage can be reffered to by names from other scopes, but _it shouldn't_. Is it correct?

Comment: If an entity has linkage, it can potentially be referred to by names from other scopes, but all the usual name lookup and hiding rules still apply. An entity having no linkage cannot possibly be referred to by names from other scopes - in `void foo() { int a; }`, `a` has no linkage and no name outside the scope could possibly refer to it.

Answer (score 2):

I guess //1 case is used for forward declaration.
But you can not do this because `A and B::A` are in totally different place.
so the option could be.

If you want to use forward declaration you will have to put `A` in the same `namespace`.
May be this would put some light what i want to say.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace B{
struct A;
}

namespace B
{
    struct A
    {
    private:
        int a;
    public:
        A() : a(10){ }
        friend void foo(A * a);
    };

    void foo(A* a)
    {
        std::cout << a -> a << std::endl;
    }
}

B::A* a = new B::A;

int main()
{
    foo(a);
}
```

Here's the 
[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ff9a7184752de25)